# javadoc warning hyperlinks in eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, hyperlink, console, javadoc, broken-links

When I generate javadoc within eclipse (version info below), the warning messages written to the eclipse console appear to be correctly hyperlinked to a java file and line number.  However, clicking on such a does nothing. Right clicking on such a hyperlink displays a context menu containing an `Open Link` item, but clicking that item also does nothing.

Any suggestions on how to get these hyperlinks to function?

Thanks,
  -- fas

Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 2

Build id: 20110218-0911
```

Comment: Want to paste the console contents ?

Comment: Hmmm... something strange: now I'm not getting *any* console output at all.  When I track that issue down, I'll paste an example.

Comment: Strange, after restarting eclipse, javadoc would not produce any console output until something else (in this case, junit) produced some console output.  After that, javadoc produces output.

Comment: Here's a sample of javadoc output that appears to be hyperlinked but does not work:


Generating C:\Tmp\javadoc\index-files\index-19.html...

Generating C:\Tmp\javadoc\index-files\index-20.html...

C:\Rogue\rogue\topic-service\src\test\java\com\quest\rogue\topicservice\rql\impl\QueryProcessorTest.java:210: warning - Tag @link: reference not found: com.quest.rogue.topicservice.rql.QueryProcessor#execute(net.ontopia.topicmaps.core.TopicIF, com.quest.rogue.util.IParameters)

Generating C:\Tmp\javadoc\index-files\index-21.html...

Comment: This is no longer an issue using a new Eclipse version:

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve the problem itself, but is a workaround that worked for me until the problem is solved:

- Copy the link from the console (without line number)
- Go to File->Open File, paste the link
- When the file is already open in the editor the link in the console works, so you can jump to the line of code and open additional links in the same file